# How to stop iFrame from reloading

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to pass a parameter to an iFrame by adding a param in the onload event as below:

```
<iframe name="myframe" src="http://test.com/hello" onload=" frames['myframe'].location.href='http://test.com/hello?uname='+getUserName();">

</iframe>
```

(getUserName is my custom function)

But the iFrame keeps loading over and over again. How do I stop this using just javascript (and not any js framework)?

Note:For certain reasons, I can write only inline javascript scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a global flag (choose an appropriate name that does not collide with any other name):

```
if (window.frames['myframe'] && !window.userSet){
    window.userSet = true;
    frames['myframe'].location.href='http://test.com/hello?uname='+getUserName();
}
```

Alternatively you can set a custom attribute to the element:

```
var userSet = this.getAttribute('data-userset');
if (window.frames['myframe'] && !userSet){
    this.setAttribute('data-userset', 'true');
    frames['myframe'].location.href='http://test.com/hello?uname='+getUserName();
}
```

Or if you don't have to invoke the event handler later on again, you can remove it:

```
if (window.frames['myframe']){
    this.onload = null;
    this.setAttribute('onload', '');
    frames['myframe'].location.href='http://test.com/hello?uname='+getUserName();
}
```

Btw. what do you have the `if` statement for? I think it will always be `true` anyway.

Comment: Oops. Was trying to set a condition, forgot to edit the code before posting it here. changed now..

Comment: @heylo: I see :) Inside the event handler you can just use `this` to reference the element the handler is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

because the HREF is changing on the `onload` and Change of HREF will reload the iFrame.

So you have to remove the `onload` to some other event.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter so that only the first time it redirects.

Initially it is `0` and redirects, the second time it is `1`, etc and hence does not redirect.

```
<script>var counter = 0</script>

<iframe name="myframe" src="http://test.com/hello"
 onload="if (window.frames['myframe'] && counter++ === 0){ frames['myframe'].location.href='http://test.com/hello?uname='+getUserName();}">
</iframe>
```

Comment: sorry, cant use a script tag :(