# How can I prevent my iframe window from reloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a tailwind components website using next js for my portfolio like this website [www.hyperui.dev](http://www.hyperui.dev). This website will have different styles made using tailwind as well as the code for creating the styles. For showing the components I'm using Iframe, but the problem is whenever I switch from "code" to "preview" of my component my Iframe gets refreshed. I want to stop the Iframe from reloading/refreshing.

I'm using the below code for my Iframe settings.

```
   <iframe
      srcDoc=``
      frameBorder="0"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      sandbox="allow-scripts"
      loading="lazy"
    />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop iFrame from reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676358/how-to-stop-iframe-from-reloading)